# 'null' is null or not an object on javascript error on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

The next code show me an error like: "null' is null or not an object" only on IE8. IE8 show the "}catch(err){" how the problem. I've been researching this issue. In a post I found that you could solve this: window.event. But I do not know where to use it. Please help.

```
<![CDATA[
     var sendRequest = function(url, callback, postData) {

        try{
        var req = createXMLHTTPObject();
        if (!req) return;
        var method = (postData) ? "POST" : "GET";
        req.open(method, url, true);
        req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
        if (postData)
          req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
          req.timeout = 65000;
          req.ontimeout = function () { ajaxRequestTimedOut(); }
          req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            try{
              if (req.readyState != 4) return;
              if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
                unlockScreen();
                openAlert('<p class="style6" style="text-align: justify;"> Error de comunicación. Presiona Aceptar para continuar.');
                lockScreen();
                setTimeout(function(){
                  sendRequest(url, callback, postData);
                  }, 500);
                return;
              }
              callback(req);
            }catch(err){ //IE8 Says this line is wrong
              openAlert('<p class="style6" style="text-align: justify;">' + err.message);         
            } 
          }
        if (req.readyState == 4) return;

        //Fix to prevent Aborted messages on IE
        req.onprogress = function () { };
        req.onerror = function () { };
        req.onabort = function(){
          unlockScreen();
          openAlert('<p class="style6" style="text-align: justify;">' + "Ocurrio un problema, favor de reintentar.");
          };
        setTimeout(function(){
          req.send("SoapRequest=" + escape(postData));
          }, 500);

      }catch(err){
        openAlert('<p class="style6" style="text-align: justify;">' + err.message);
      }
    };
    ]]>
```

What's wrong? thank you very much!

Comment: Remove code until you've identified the line that is breaking.

Comment: Try removing things like `unlockScreen`, `lockScreen`, and `callback(req)` one at a time. See if the absence of any of these resolves the issue. If so, investigate the contents of the significant method for greater insight.

Comment: The problem is that I execute this method once for show a list in a table. Every one row have an icon that execute this method again but this time reedirect to another page and show this issue. Well, the problem is close, the problem wasnt in this code, it was in the callback method and its difficult to explain the trust reason, technically it was an error of sintax. Thank u so much anywhere.